# Passing userform as parameter to form launching utility

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I am trying to create a utility which launches a new instance of a specified userform with custom parameters, but I am having trouble passing the desired userform to the utility.

In a module:

```
Public Sub LaunchForm(MachID As String, FormType As UserForm)

Dim Form As New FormType

With Form
    .MachineID = MachID
    .Show
End With  

End Sub
```

In the userform from which the form is to be launched:

```
Private Sub RemovePart32_Click()
   LaunchForm "Machine32", RemovePart
End Sub
```

When I click the "RemovePart32" button, I get a compile error "user defined type not defined". I am guessing that I should pass the userform as a string but I get a type error if I do that and I'm not sure how to get around that. Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FormType` is actually a variable that you've declared as one of the parameters in `LaunchForm`, not a type.  And so you cannot create a new instance of a variable.

Since you want to invoke the `Show` method of the userform passed to `LaunchForm`, you should pass the userform by value as a generic object.

Alternatively, you can pass the userform by reference as the actual class of the userform, which would be the name of the userform itself (ie. UserForm1 or whatever else you may have named it).

So, for example, to pass your userform by value as a generic object, try...

```
Public Sub LaunchForm(MachID As String, ByVal Form As Object)

    With Form
        .MachineID = MachID
        .Show
    End With

End Sub
```

Note, when it comes to objects, it's the reference to that object that gets passed to the called procedure.  And that reference can be passed ByRef and ByVal.

When passed ByRef, the reference is passed by reference and the called procedure can change the object to which that reference refers to.

When passed ByVal, only a copy of the reference is passed.

For a more detailed explanation, see [this](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/byrefbyval.aspx) article.

Comment: Worked perfectly! If I understand correctly, passing the form ByVal creates a new instance of the object whereas if it where passed ByRef if would be trying to set the MachineID property of the original form, which I think would not work?

I had tried passing the form as an object but I couldn't quite get it to work, this was very helpfull.

Comment: It looks like I forgot to notify you of my edit to my post.  So, if you haven't already done so, please see my edited post.

Comment: Just saw this, thanks for letting me know! Ive been coding in vba 24/7 since I asked this question and reading back through this makes me realize how much I've learned. I'll accept your answer as soon as I am allowed to!